Can't prepare protein or Docking in Discovery Studio
First of all, I don't know if I posted in the write place or not so forgive me.
Hi, As the title said.
I recently installed discovery studio and tried to activate it as Localhost and everything worked like a charm but only those 2 in the title don't.
When I try to prepare any protein, and I have tried more than one, this happens:
For example: 1EQG:
Open coordinate file C:/Program Files/BIOVIA/PPS/web/jobs/user/B6941BC0-AB72-41B0-81A0-E27C105216A1/Intermediate/SideChains/HBuild/1EQG_hbuild.crd failed

And when I found a prepared protein and I try docking at it the refrence ligand, this happens:
charmm.log not found. CHARMm has failed to run.
 Docking failed.
 Please review the Failed Ligands file 

I tried too many solutions and tried reinstalling multiple times and nothing worked so I was hoping that someone here can help.
Thanks a lot and sorry for disturbing.

Its not https://www.3ds.com/products/biovia/user-communities

https://forums-academiccharmm.org/

https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Charmm

I’m voting to close this question because it seems to belong on bioinformatics.stackexchange.com instead, as the comments indicate.
